# Entity Framework n-tier solution

Tags: entity-framework, poco, n-tier-architecture

I'm creating a new project that is following closely to the design used by this example.

http://www.toplinestrategies.com/dotneters/net/wcf-entity-framework-and-n-tier-solutions-part-2/?lang=en

I have a WPF or ASP.NET app that talks to a WCF service which then sends it to the business layer to do most of the work.

The POCO objects are generated and then that template is moved to a Model project which will allow me to access those objects in the business and data layers. My question is what purpose does the Data Access Layer provide in this situation? It seems to be only holding the .edmx files.

Is this standard practice, or would I get better efficiency by simply putting the .edmx files into the Business Layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DAL generally provides with mapping between models and database tables. According to your description, you moved the mapping part into models. I am not sure that's a good practice though. As database table, for example, changes you need to change/build model project as well. What if you decide later to use NHibernate instead of EF? For these reasons, I think the mapping should be in DAL and DAL can be a separate project.

Comment: So then your suggestion would be that I leave out the model layer and just reference the Data layer from the Business Logic layer in order to pass around the POCO objects? Or should my data layer contain the business logic?

Comment: For similar reasons, I would separate BLL and DAL. In BLL, I would have generic repository class to get data from DAL.

Comment: Forgive me for not understanding. But what would be the benefit of using a repository class over using the generated POCO's?

Comment: I think the biggest benefit would be independence from any specific data access method. If you directly use POCO context, your whole BLL is dependent on EF context. But when you use repository interface in BLL, it is free from that. Later, if you want to use, SQL CE, you can just implement that interface. BLL is not dependent on any data access method.

Comment: Do you have any links to examples of what you are talking about. I have seen plenty of information on using a repository interface, however they all seem to use the POCO objects - otherwise how do you know what object you are returning?

Comment: I don't think you understood correctly. I am not saying not to use POCO objects in your repository implementation, but to use repository interface in BLL. Still no? You will have IRepository interface and EFRepository implementing that interface and using POCO object, right? You will entirely achieve that independence by using IRepository interface rather than EFRepository in BLL. That's what I am saying.

Comment: I think I get what you are saying, however when looking at setting up a repository I don't see the advantage of doing that considering I'm already using an ORM in EF. But thank you for your input.